# Is there a way to put a Queue Worker in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, queue, symfony4

Currently I am working in a Symfony 4 environment that needs to periodically (by cron) work through a queue of commands/actions, without having to install server-packages like RabbitMQ.

In Laravel there is the magnificent Queuing system that works with database-synced queues and a listening worker. Is something like this available for Symfony 4?

I've tried installing [JMSJobQueueBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSJobQueueBundle) and [QueueBundle](https://github.com/nicholasnet/QueueBundle), but both fail to install in Symfony 4.

Answer (score 3):

you have this bundle https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev wich provide a lot options

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bernhard (or even easier: the [BernhardBundle for Symfony](https://github.com/bernardphp/BernardBundle).

It will allow you to add queuing to your application and supports the filesystem as persistence store, so there is no need for external software.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

[DtcQueueBundle](https://github.com/mmucklo/DtcQueueBundle) is also a nice queue/worker library, it [supports Symfony 4](https://github.com/mmucklo/DtcQueueBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/symfony4.md) and (very important) is still actively maintained.